# Modeling with Multiple Values per Variable, per Observation

Tags: python, feature-engineering, keras, categorical-encoding

I'm attempting to develop an autoencoder on top of medical claims data that have mutliple values per category because a claim often has multiple lines associated with it. For example, let's say (but not hope) something really bad happens to me where I have to enter the hospital through the Emergency Room, have surgery, and then end up in the hospital's Intensive Care Unit. Each of these hospital locations has a different "revenue code" associated with it, and the claim would look something like the following:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'claim_id': ['A213', 'A213', 'A213'], 
                   'claim_line': [1, 2, 3], 
                   'revenue_code': ['450', '360', '200']})


print(df)

#   claim_id  claim_line revenue_code
#0     A213           1          450
#1     A213           2          360
#2     A213           3          200
```

Revenue code '450' represent Emergency Room, revenue code '360' represents surgery, and revenue code '200' represents intensive care unit.

As part of my autoencoding model, I want to perform categorical feature embedding to reduce the amount of sparsity I would otherwise have because of features with high cardinality (like revenue code). But I have multiple `revenue_code` values for the same observation.

#### My Thought: Concatenate all of the revenue codes together into a single value.

This approach would put all of the revenue codes in a single value, and then the new column would be transformed into ordinal values to feed into a Keras `Embedding()` layer. I don't care about the order of the revenue codes within the same claim, so an example with two claims would look like the following:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'claim_id': ['A213', 'A213', 'A213', 'B545', 'B545'], 
                   'claim_line': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2], 
                   'revenue_code': ['450', '360', '200', '360', '710']})


print(df2)

#  claim_id  claim_line revenue_code
#0     A213           1          450
#1     A213           2          360
#2     A213           3          200
#3     B545           1          360
#4     B545           2          710
```

Would turn into the following:

```
#  claim_id revenue_code
#0     A213  200-360-450
#1     B545      360-710
```

My only concern with this approach is that I would lose the ability to associate categorical variables with continuous variables. An example would be an infusion procedure code. The approach I mentioned above would allow me to capture every time an infusion procedure code is present on a claim, but it would not allow me to identify *how many* infusions took place (a quantity housed in a separate column).

I'm looking for advice from anyone who has faced a similar problem (agnostic of industry).